# Join two tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am very new to Laravel and here I have one simple question. I need to join one more table to the following

```
   return $products = Product::where('product_type_id', 1)
                            ->where('quantity', '>=', 50)
                             ->where('deleted', 0)
                            ->orderBy('price')
                            ->paginate(100);
```

I have another table name product_img where all the images of products are stored. Need to fetch all the records where product id is available in product_img table and where file is not equal to 'Noimg.jpg'. I tried different solutions but didn't worked. How to join two tables in Laravel?

I tried to do the following:

```
$products = Product::leftJoin('product_img', function($join) {
                                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_img.product_id')
                                ->where('product_img.file', '!=', 'Noimg.jpg');
                             }) ;
                                ->where('quantity', '>=', 100)
                                ->where('deleted', 0)
                                ->orderBy('price')
                                ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: replace `leftJoin` with `join` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$products = Product::join('product_img', 'products.id', '=', 'product_img.product_id')
                                ->where('product_img.file', '!=', 'Noimg.jpg')
                                ->where('quantity', '>=', 100)
                                ->where('deleted', 0)
                                ->orderBy('price')
                                ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct symbol for Not Equal is <> in SQL, and != is for programming languages.

```
 $products = Product::join('product_img', function($join) {
                                $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_img.product_id')
                                ->where('product_img.file', '<>', 'Noimg.jpg');
                             }) ;
                                ->where('quantity', '>=', 100)
                                ->where('deleted', 0)
                                ->orderBy('price')
                                ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: query worked but products are listing where records with Noimg.jpg or where records are not in the image table

Comment: I need to run this query in Laravel -> SELECT a.* FROM `products` as a JOIN `product_img` b ON a.id = b.product_id WHERE b.product_id = a.id AND b.file!='Noimg.jpg' GROUP BY `id` DESC ORDER BY `created_at` DESC

Comment: yes, It didn't worked.. Actually what I am getting in the raw query Is not what I am getting when I run the code